# How to remove Menu Bar from Windows 11 File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

The said [menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Riu.png) started showing up in my Windows 11 File Explorer out of nowhere. Can anyone help me out to get rid of it?

[image: unwanted menu bar]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @OP - I added a repair step to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 from the following link worked for me. Option 1 "Always show menus" was not available in my current Win 11 Pro version 22621.675:

> **Add or Remove File Explorer Menu Bar using REG file**
>
> (Contents of REG file for reference) Code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"AlwaysShowMenus"=dword:00000000
```

> 1 Create a new .reg file with the above content and save the file to your desktop.
>
> 2 Double click/tap on the .reg file to execute it.
>
> 3 When prompted, click/tap on Run, Yes (UAC), Yes, and OK to approve.
>
> 4 You can now delete the downloaded .reg file.

Source: [Add or Remove Menu Bar in File Explorer in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-menu-bar-in-file-explorer-in-windows-11.7643/)

Comment: Didn't even need to restart Explorer, the menu bar disappeared as soon as I set the dword to 0. Thanks!